# Many to many relation joining - Track sales based on device while a user have many transactions on multiple devices

Tags: sql

I am running a report on how to group sales on unique *device_id* and got stuck. The setting is:

A user can have many transactions at different timestamps. In the meanwhile, that user may change device, or/and log-in from multiple devices as well. While a summary of sales grouped by user (user_id is unique) is simple, a summary of sales group by unique device_id is more challenging (caused by the many to many relationship of user_id to device_id).

I have made the join to two final tables below and got stuck:

## user_dev

```
user_id -- dev_id -- dev_created_date
1 ----------- 1 ------ 2018-07-05 07:38:23
1 ----------- 2 ------ 2018-08-05 09:39:44
2 ----------- 2 ------ 2018-07-15 02:28:35
2 ----------- 3 ------ 2018-09-11 14:17:32
```

## user_trans

```
user_id -- trans_id -- trans_time
1 ----------- 1 ------ 2018-07-05 07:48:23
1 ----------- 2 ------ 2018-07-08 05:13:12
1 ----------- 3 ------ 2018-08-15 11:18:15
2 ----------- 4 ------ 2018-08-29 13:21:22
2 ----------- 5 ------ 2018-09-12 02:37:17
```

The desired return table have those columns:

trans_id (unique), user_id, device_id

The rule for matching a *trans_id* to a *device_id* is to have the same *user_id*, and *trans_time* >=  *dev_created_date*, and *trans_time* - *dev_created_date* is the lowest positive possible.

For example:

*trans_id* = 1 will be matched with *device_id* 1 given same *user_id* = 1, and *trans_time* is closest right after *dev_created_date*

*trans_id* = 2 will be matched with *device_id* 1 given same *user_id* = 1, and *trans_time* is still closest right after *dev_created_date* of *device_id* 1.

*trans_id* = 3 will be matched with *device_id* 2 given same *user_id* = 1, and *trans_time* is closest right after *dev_created_date* of *device_id* 2 (instead of 1).

## This is my expected return table:

```
user_id -- trans_id -- dev_id
1 ----------- 1 ------ 1
1 ----------- 2 ------ 1
1 ----------- 3 ------ 2
2 ----------- 4 ------ 2
2 ----------- 5 ------ 3
```

I was unable to join the *user_dev* and *user_trans* table as *user_id* in both table is not unique.

Sorry that I forgot to post the code for the table creation.

```
create TABLE user_trans (user_id integer, trans_id integer, 
                trans_time timestamp);
insert into user_trans values (1, 1,'2018-07-05 07:48:23');
insert into user_trans values (1, 2,'2018-07-08 05:13:12');
insert into user_trans values (1, 3,'2018-08-15 11:18:15');
insert into user_trans values (2, 4,'2018-08-29 13:21:22');
insert into user_trans values (2, 5,'2018-09-12 02:37:17');
```

And for the other table

```
create TABLE user_dev (user_id integer, dev_id integer, 
                    dev_created_date timestamp);
insert into user_dev values (1, 1,'2018-07-05 07:38:23');
insert into user_dev values (1, 2,'2018-08-05 09:39:44');
insert into user_dev values (2, 2,'2018-07-15 02:28:35');
insert into user_dev values (2, 3,'2018-09-11 14:17:32');
```

Comment: In order to do this I think you are going to need to have device_ID in the transactions table.  Tying transactions together based on nearest timestamp is sure to create unreliable datasets.

Comment: @alexherm I totally agree such information should be tracked for each transaction. Unfortunately, historical data does not have such field and I have to make assumption on how to link a transaction to a device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I don't missunderstood what you want. First, I calculate the min (trans_time - dev_created_date) for every trans_id, and then JOIN the two tables aplliyng the rule that the diff between the two dates gonna be equal to the one I previusly calculate. I hope it works:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.trans_id, u.dev_id
FROM user_dev u
JOIN user_trans t ON u.user_id = t.user_id AND t.trans_time >= u.dev_created_date
JOIN (SELECT t.trans_id, MIN(t.trans_time - u.dev_created_date) AS min
      FROM user_dev u
      JOIN user_trans t ON u.user_id = t.user_id AND t.trans_time >= u.dev_created_date
      GROUP BY t.trans_id) AS t_min ON t.trans_id = t_min.trans_id
WHERE (t.trans_time - u.dev_created_date) = t_min.min
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian, your code works flawlessly for my goal. I am new to SQL and does not know that two tables can be joined on columns that does not have unique value. This is a great learning for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
select ud.*, ut.*
from (select ud.*,
             (select min(ut.trans_time)
              from user_trans ut
              where ut.user_id = ud.user_id and
                    ut.trans_time > ud.dev_created_date
             ) as min_trans_time
      from user_dev
     ) ud join
     user_trans ut
     on ut.user_id = ud.user_id and
        ut.trans_time = min_trans_time;
```

The subquery calculates the first transaction time after the create date.  The `join` then brings in the rest of the columns.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help on this issue. Your code also returns the right device_id per transaction_id as I wish. However, your subquery returns only 4 rows and drop transaction #2. I think it was drop because both transaction #1 and #2 are from device_id #1, and the min drop #2 row. Thanks for helping me to learn :D